# Laravel 8 with Breeze, setted the existing user table for Auth, but doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-breeze

I have to build a new system with a kind of old-style pre-existing MySQL database tables with Laravel 8 with Breeze.
Already have a user data table that is totally different from the basic Auth system in Laravel 8.
I am trying to figure out to make Auth system but it doesn't work right.

This is my `User` model class.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'tb_user_info';

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        //'passwd',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
    {
        $this->attributes['passwd'] = \DB::raw("password('$password')");
    }
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->passwd;
    }
}
```

And this is my `store` method in `AuthenticatedSessionController`, which I figured it is using in login.

```
public function store(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'mem_id' => ['required', 'email'],
            'passwd' => ['required'],
        ]);

       $user = User::select('mem_id', 'passwd')->where('mem_id', $request->mem_id)->first();
        if ($user->mem_id == $request->mem_id && $user->passwd == $this->sql_password($request->passwd)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();

            return redirect('/dashboard');
        }

        return back()->withErrors([
            'mem_id' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
        ]);
    }
```

I thought it simply works, but after I try to login, it doesn't work at all, just keep redirecting back to the login page. I looked up the `Network` tab in Chrome, it seems like the `dashboard` page was called but it shows `302 Found` and called the `login` page again.

Which part should I lookup for this situation?
I am working on this for 3 days, nothing came up for a good solution.
Please, please help me, I would be appreciated just a few tips.

Ps. Please don't answer like `stop using the MySQL password for password` or `why don't you make a new database table?` because it's meaningless answers. I would do that already if I can. This is a very limited situation at work. Please understand.

Comment: is it redirecting back to login with errors? also make sure your sessions are working propertly

Comment: @lagbox Actually there are no errors. And how I can check my sessions are working properly?

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem happens to me once.

if you check dd() in store function and it does not work I think.  I think 302 reason is not in current store method check `LoginRequest $request` method. before hit to the `store` method function need to fullfill the `LoginRequest $request` therefore problem should be there

go to the LoginRequest method and there should be validation or usecase with `password` and you are using `passwd` instead of using `password` try to fix that error

Comment: I already tried the ``dd()`` in the `store` method and it works. And it's the same result I changed the `LoginRequest $request` to just `Request $request`.